# Protégé: Sub data properties removed from super data property after reloading

Tags: rdf, owl, ontology, protege

Screenshots:

- [before saving](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7qjJY.png)
- [after reloading](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MsEbD.png)

I am encountering an issue and I do not seem to understand why it is happening.
I had to create an ontology in Protogé and I used data properties which I stored in super properties with sub properties; I have linked these to eacher using the SubProperty Of function. I have also linked them to the correct domains and provided them with a range.

However, when I try to save and then reload the files, the structure I added is removed.
How can I fix this?

I tried changing the tags, unlinking them from the largest property but to no avail.
I tried looking online but couldn't find any reason.

Comment: I suppose, these properties should be object properties, not data properties.

Comment: Can you show the output file?